# Unable to use the minikube command and create the virtualization

Tags: minikube

Docker and Kubernetes are popular with millions of developers and programmers. So I imagine this will be resolved quickly here.

I am studying linkedin tutorials.Going over the same topic with different instructors provides clarity by having the same topic explained by different views.

Prior to going through the current tutorial, I was able to successfully run

GO to the BOIS of your Computer, Enable virtualization, and save it run again with and start to create the container and for docker context CLI using below command.

Input command

---

```
docker context use default
```

output command

```
default 
Current context is now "default"
```